# Jquery/Javascript append doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im testing this jQuery code but it is not running. I opened the console (F12) and after I pasted the test code and it compiles it perfectly. While Im removing the src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" and getting the alert out of the $(document).ready(function(){  then  alerts works but I get that message from the console:"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ". I wonder why is that? Any help please?

Here is my testing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">


$(document).ready(function(){    
alert('Hi!');
$("#content").append('<div class=\'toolbarBox toolbarHead\' style=\'background-color: #F8F8F8;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;margin-bottom: 10px;padding: 5px 0;border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-o-border-radius: 3px;position: relative;\'><div class=\'pageTitle\'><h3 style = \'font-size: 1.6em;font-weight: normal;line-height: 52px;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;\'><span id=\'current_obj\' style=\'font-weight: normal;\'><span class=\'breadcrumb item-0\'>My Affiliates<img alt=\'&gt;\' style=\'margin-right:5px\' src=\'../img/admin/separator_breadcrumb.png\'></span><span class=\'breadcrumb item-1\'>Affiliates</span></span></h3></div></div>'); 
$("#content").append("<iframe style=\'width: 100%;height: 100%;\' src=\'http://www.myaffiliates.gr/\'></iframe>");

});
```

Answer (score 8):

Your script tags are not proper

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// your script
</script>
```

A script element can contain either `src` or body but not both.

[Script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src) : [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)

> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be
>   used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.

Comment: Can you explain me why it need 2 scripts elements?

Comment: @Sergiti because that is how script tag works... if the `src` attribute is specified then the content between the opening and closing tags must be empty - http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Hi!');
        $("#content").append('<div class=\"toolbarBox toolbarHead\" style=\"background-color: #F8F8F8;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;margin-bottom: 10px;padding: 5px 0;border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-o-border-radius: 3px;position: relative;\"><div class=\"pageTitle\"><h3 style =\"font-size: 1.6em;font-weight: normal;line-height: 52px;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;\"><span id=\"current_obj\" style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><span class=\"breadcrumb item-0\">My Affiliates<img alt=\"&gt;\" style=\"margin-right:5px\" src=\"../img/admin/separator_breadcrumb.png\"></span><span class=\"breadcrumb item-1\">Affiliates</span></span></h3></div></div>');
        $("#content").append("<iframe style=\"width: 100%;height: 100%;\" src=\"http://www.myaffiliates.gr/\"></iframe>");

    });
</script>
```